# Как отправлять данные в input классы?

Tags: парсер, golang

У меня есть `<input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu8287_input" name="custom_U8287" tabindex="12">` мне нужно передать данные email адерса посредством POST запроса, как мне это сделать? Как передать данные в запрос? 
Использую Golang

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="hidden" name="email">` вам поможет. Добавьте код в форме, вместе с вашим и он будет передан в обработчик.

```html
<?
  echo '1 = ' . $_POST['1'] . '<br>';
  echo 'скрытое = ' . $_POST['hid'] . '<br>';
  
?>

<form action="./" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="1" id="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="скрытое">
  <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

Добавьте код выше в свой файл и увидите, как передаются данные. [Вот тут мануал](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type)

Comment: Можно поподробнее? не очень понял, особенно не знаю как это предоставить в  запросе и реализовать. Пожалуйста можно код для примера

Comment: Добавил код и ссылку на мат часть.